# Sending data from an activity to its fragment using bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to send a Parcelable array from MainActivity to one of its fragment using bundle. My code is

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
bundle.putParcelableArray(key, MyParcelableArray);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

When debugged, I found that MyParcelableArray is not null but bundle mParcelledData is null. Thus, it is throwing a null pointer error.
Why is this happening?

I'm retrieving code in the fragments onCreateView as below.

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
Parcelable[] parcelables = bundle.getParcelableArray(MainActivity.key);
```

getting null pointer in the above line.

Comment: There's no `mParcelledData` in the code you are showing. When and where do you get the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: share your code where you are retrieving your parcelable list

Comment: Object need to implement Parcelable interface. Then, you can send it in a bundle by using the Bundle.putParcelableArray() - method.

[click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArray%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%5B%5D%29)

Comment: @dhke mParcelledData is a parameter of bundle. I found it when debugging the code.

Comment: I like using Serialization

Comment: @ZumryMohamed : I have implemented Parcelable interface. MyParcelableArray is returning a ParcelableArray.

Comment: try to use just `putExra` instead of `putParcelableArray`

Answer (score 0):

While opening a fragment use below code

```
Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("data", MyParcelableArray);
ListFrag newFragment = new ListFrag ();
newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

While obtaining that bundle data in fragment use below code

```
Bundle b = getArguments();
ArrayList<collection> yourArrayList = (ArrayList<collection>) b.getSerializable("data");
```